# How to create a field with a list of neighboring residential lots in QGIS?

Tags: field-calculator, geometry, list, aggregate, concatenation

I need to create a field with a list containing the 'name' information of the geometries that intersect each of the existing geometries. They are residential lots, and I need to list the adjacent ones. The information is in the same layer.
I tried the expression below in fiel-calculator, but it doesn't list all the names os neighbors and sometimes lists '@parent'.
`aggregate(layer:='lots',aggregate:='concatenate',expression:="name",filter:=intersects(@geometry,geometry(@parent)),concatenator:='; ')`
I try with the buffer to, because with the buffer i made a rule-based symbology to make some layouts with atlas like this:
[image]

But didn't work.
so, i wnat to list all of the white ones o after make some documents with 'atlas'

Answer (score 0):

Tip: when sharing code, use code blocks with triple backticks above and below the code. And if it's long, spanning multiple lines for readability.

Also listing what layers you have and a picture of each would be helpful to understand your question.

New lines between explanations also help people understand everything. Your entire explanation is one jumbled paragraph.

The expression you've tried is on the right track, but it seems like it might not be capturing all the neighbors due to the way the intersects function is used. Additionally, the use of @parent might not be necessary or correct in this context.

Try this:

```
aggregate(
 layer:= 'lots',
 aggregate:='concatenate',
 expression:= "name",
 filter:= intersects(geometry(@atlas_geometry), geometry(@parent)),
 concatenator:= '; '
)
```